# HTML5 video javascript controls - restart video

Tags: javascript, html, video

I know how to start and stop a video with play() and pause(), but how do I put a video back to the start in HTML5 using javascript? is there a way to move the pointer back to the start?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Set the [`currentTime`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-iframe-element.html#media-elements) property back to `0`.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the answer. $('#mov1').get(0).currentTime = 0;

Comment: @startupthekid — Nobody suggested trying to use it on a jQuery object and it isn't a function/method, it's a property holding a number.

Answer (score 36):

To have a proper `stop` functionality you could do the following:

```
var video = document.getElementById('vidId');
// or video = $('.video-selector')[0];
video.pause();
video.currentTime = 0;
video.load();
```

Note: This is the only version that worked for me in chrome using `nodejs` (`meteorjs`) in the backend, serving `webm`, `mp4`, `ogg` files

Comment: Using `video.play()` after I set the `currentTime` to `0` works as well. What's the reason it must be `video.load()` here?

Comment: using load() before play() helped me restart the video in safari when using webm. 

Answer (score 0):

load() will reload video and put it back to start