# Reset a video on mouse out using HTML5 and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I am trying to get the video that appears after the hover to reset to the start once the mouse leaves, here is the [link to my test](http://motion-master-templates.com/test-page).  I found this in my [search for an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402158/html5-video-javascript-controls-restart-video)
But I can not figure it out how to make that work.

Here is where I got the code for the javascript: [Link to code](http://www.trustweb.it/it/blog/download/jquery-html5-video-tooltip.html)

Any help or advice would be great.  Thank you! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your site uses jQuery:

```
$(".h5vt").mouseout(function() {
    $("video").get(0).currentTime = 0;
})
```

Just bind a `mouseout` event to the image that rewinds the video.

You should add an `id` attribute to video and access it with `$("#myvideoid").get(0)` or `document.getElementById("myvideoid")` instead of with `$("video").get(0)` as in my example.  My selector code is just a workaround due to the fact that your video element lacks an `id`.

Comment: Thank you very much again, I have another question :)

Do you know of a way to shut this all off so it does not work on an iPad or iPhone as that will keep the video from continuing to play even when a user moves on.

The other option I found was doing something like this hover: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/#toc-fun-css
It is the 5.3 + CSS example.

Which one do you think I should stick to?  The new one I found seems a lot cleaner without having to worry about hover on iPad or the popup going off the screen.

Thank you very much for your time. :)

Comment: I'm afraid I can't halp you too much there -- I'd suggest just trying something out, and if you run into problems, start a new question about exactly what you want to happen on mobile devices.